# Proof of vanishing vector expression

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If I expand the following expression for the 3 components I see that the expression vanishes, $|\mathbf{n}|=1$: 
$$
\left(\mathbf{n}\times (\mathbf{n}\times \mathbf{x})\right)\cdot \mathbf{x}
+\left(\mathbf{n}\times (\mathbf{n}\times \mathbf{x})\right)\cdot \left(\mathbf{n}\times \left(\mathbf{n}\times \mathbf{x}\right)\right)=\mathbf{0}
$$

Is there a more elegant proof?

**EDIT** A simple picture also give a proof. I'm looking for a algebraic proof, like some manipulation using vector-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let ${\bf a}\bot {\bf n}$ with $|{\bf a}|=1$ and ${\bf b}={\bf n}\times {\bf a}$. Then if the expression vanishes for ${\bf x}\in\{ {\bf a},{\bf b},{\bf n}\}$ then you are done since they constitue a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$